# Why does this IF statement change the variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Why does the variable change within this if statment

```
$userid = 500;
echo "User ID" . $userid; // Outputs 500

if($userid=362) {   
  echo "User ID" . $userid . "x"; // Outputs 362
}
```

Comment: Because `=` is assignment; `==` (or `===`) is comparison

Comment: too localized question, it will help no one in the future

Answer (score 3):

`=` is the assignment operator. So your `if` statement is assigning the value of 362 to `$userid`. What you want to use is `==` which is a comparison operator:

```
if($userid=362) {
```

should be

```
if($userid==362) {
```